# how can I make this code more structured or easier to see, the if statement here is not that good

Tags: xslt

I want to make a good if or else or a for each statement what I have now is a kindy messy

this is what I have now but it is too messy
help?

```
<xsl:if test="unit = '110-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>PCE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '120-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>PCE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '130-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>MTR</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '140-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>PCE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '150-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>SE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '160-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>PCE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '167-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>SE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '168-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>SE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '169-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>SE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '170-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>SE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '171-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>SE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '172-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>SE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '172-02'"><ORDER_UNIT>SE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '173-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>SE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '174-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>SE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '175-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>SE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '180-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>PCE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '190-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>PCE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '200-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>PCE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '205-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>PCE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '210-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>MTR</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '220-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>PCE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '230-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>PCE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '260-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>PCE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '270-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>PCE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '280-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>MTR</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '310-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>PCE</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '350-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>MTR</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '360-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>MTR</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '370-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>MTR</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '380-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>MTR</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '390-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>MTR</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="unit = '400-01'"><ORDER_UNIT>MTR</ORDER_UNIT></xsl:if>
```

Comment: which xsl version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to make a good if or else

For mutually exclusive conditions, you should be using `xsl:choose`, not a series of `xsl:if` instructions:

```
<ORDER_UNIT>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '110-01'">PCE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '120-01'">PCE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '130-01'">MTR</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '140-01'">PCE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '150-01'">SE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '160-01'">PCE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '167-01'">SE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '168-01'">SE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '169-01'">SE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '170-01'">SE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '171-01'">SE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '172-01'">SE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '172-02'">SE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '173-01'">SE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '174-01'">SE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '175-01'">SE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '180-01'">PCE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '190-01'">PCE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '200-01'">PCE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '205-01'">PCE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '210-01'">MTR</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '220-01'">PCE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '230-01'">PCE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '260-01'">PCE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '270-01'">PCE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '280-01'">MTR</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '310-01'">PCE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '350-01'">MTR</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '360-01'">MTR</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '370-01'">MTR</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '380-01'">MTR</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '390-01'">MTR</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="unit = '400-01'">MTR</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</ORDER_UNIT>
```

This way, when `test="unit = '130-01'"` returns true, the resulting string `"MTR"` will be returned immediately and you will eliminate the redundant evaluation of 30 subsequent tests - thus saving time, electricity and the environment.

You can increase the efficiency even further by testing for the most frequent values first.

---

Another option is to place all the test values in a variable (or even in a separate document) and use a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key) to lookup the corresponding result from there - but this is practical only if you're using XSLT 2.0 or higher (though still possible in XSLT 1.0 with a bit more code).

Answer (score 1):

Well two things you can do are:

1) Stop repeating the output node, so:

```
<ORDER_UNIT>
<xsl:if test="condition">value</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="condition">value</xsl:if>
</ORDER_UNIT>
```

2) Group repeated output values:

```
<xsl:if test="unit = '167-01' or unit = '168-01'">SE</xsl:if>
```

Comment: While I agree with 1) I think 2) will likely create more clutter if you consider for example 10 cases for the `SE` output value.

Comment: Fair point. Fine if there's just a few options but not for 10.